# How to handle notification count when app is in background in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I have successfully handled notifications when app is in foreground by FirebaseMessagingService class. which will generate notification from app using this code:

```
 private void sendNotification(String type, String typeID, String messageBody, String title) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    try {
        count = MazkaraPref.getInstance().getInt(getApplicationContext(), MazkaraPref.PreferenceKey.notification_count, 0);
        count++;
        Log.e("count", ":" + count);
        MazkaraPref.getInstance().saveInt(getApplicationContext(), MazkaraPref.PreferenceKey.notification_count, count);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This way I have handled Notification count when application is running in foreground. But when app is in backgorund we have no control to generate notification or count notification. So if i want to know how many notifications are pending in status bar or how many notifications are arrived at the time of SplashScreen open. How can i achieve this Notification count.I have tried code above but it works if app is running only. I am not getting it how to get pending notification count.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the count in onMessageReceived method of FirebaseMessagingService, It will get called even when app is in background.

Comment: No, it is not calling onMessageReceived() when app is in background already tried after reading  "https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device".  @Anandroid